# Pyinstaller issue on the colleague PC

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I built a script, that pulls data from SQL Server and produces excel file with Pivot Table, Chart and Slicers.

I used pyinstaller (on Windows) to create executable file, so I can share it with my colleagues, therefore they don't need to have Python installed on their PC's (Windows as well).

`pyinstaller --onefile filename.py` - used to create executable file.

When I run it on my PC, everything works great, but when my colleague tries to run it on his PC (I copied all files and folders (build, dist) on USB), script breaks with error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "filename.py", line 14, in <module>
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
[34780] Failed to execute script 'filename' due to unhandled exception!
```

It doesn't make sense, because it runs fine on my PC as mentioned above and all SQL Server credentials are stored in the executable file, so technically my colleague is using same credentials as I do.

Comment: to use pyodbc library, the odbc driver manager should be installed on user's system. The python script needs this driver to connect to sql server.

Comment: Depending on how you connect, your colleague has to have (A) the same SQL Server ODBC driver installed on their machine that you are using in your code or (B) an identical data source name configured in their machine.

Comment: Thank You, how can I check what version or whatever of SQL Server ODBC driver installed on my PC?

Comment: For Windows, drivers are found under Data Sources. But the specific way you connect to SQL Server is found in the connection string in `pyodbc.connect()` in your Python code. If your connection string is referencing a specific driver it will be in braces , e.g. `pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Your Driver Here}...`